# Unable to remove from superview (swift2)

Tags: uiview, swift2, uianimation

I am unable to remove from superview with the following code?
Why is this?I have tried everything but seems that it is not working at all.I am adding more details so I don't get this very annoying alert that tells me that my post is mostly code....

```
   let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OrderViewController")
            controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 100, self.view.frame.size.height/2 - 100, 200, 200)

        if sender.selected {

            sender.selected = false

            controller.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

            [UIView .animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

               controller.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);

                }, completion:  { finished in

               controller.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
                controller.view .removeFromSuperview()
               controller.removeFromParentViewController()


            })]
            print("close")

        }

        else {

            sender.selected = true

           addChildViewController(controller)
            view.addSubview(controller.view)
            controller.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

          controller.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
            [UIView .animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

                controller.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

                }, completion: nil)]


          print("present")

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a weird mix of objective-c syntax (the square brackets around your UIView animation block) and swift. I'm surprised if this is even compiling without errors!

You're almost there, the main issue is that each time this block of code is called you're instantiating a new instance of an 'OrderViewController'.

You only want to create this if it doesn't exist (when you want to show it). When you're ready to hide it you want to grab a reference to the existing controller and do the animations etc to hide it.

To do that you'll need to keep a reference to it outside of the local scope of that code block.

Here's an example showing how you might do that:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // keep a reference to the OrderViewController after it's been created
    var controller:UIViewController?

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        // instead of using button selected state, just check to see if 
        // self.controller is nil or not

        if let existingController = self.controller {
            // controller already exists, lets hide it

            existingController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

                existingController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);

                }, completion:  { _ in

                    existingController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
                    existingController.view.removeFromSuperview()
                    existingController.removeFromParentViewController()

                    // make this nil, so that next time the button is
                    // tapped we'll go though the process of creating it again
                    self.controller = nil

            })
            print("close")
        }
        else {
            // controller doesn't exist, lets instanstiate and show it

            let newController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OrderViewController")

            newController.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2 - 100, self.view.frame.size.height/2 - 100, 200, 200)

            addChildViewController(newController)
            view.addSubview(newController.view)
            newController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

            newController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01)

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {

                newController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity

                }, completion:  { _ in

                    // keep a reference to this controller you've just created,
                    // so that next time the button is tapped you can close it
                    self.controller = newController
            })

            print("present")

        }
    }
}
```

If you're working on a really simple app (just a couple of screens) then this method is okay.

But.... if you're planning on something more complex you might want to investigate using either a custom `UISegue`, or a mix of   `UIPresentationController` and `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` so that all of this animation logic doesn't get locked into your view controller code.

Comment: thanks for that. I do come from obj-c background and still trying to grasp the new syntax. Just a question though. Why is it better to check if controller is nil or not instead of using the button selected and then check?

Comment: you're welcome! There's nothing wrong with using button selection for your logic, but for me it felt a little more natural to use the optional state of the controller ("does't exist? make it!", "Already exists? remove it!") vs. the button selected state ("hmm, does 'selected' mean create or remove the controller?"). Also, if you're switching from Obj-C to Swift you should take the time to read and really understand optionals, and that you understand what statements like `if let existingController = self.controller` are doing.